# How to remove the border of Tabhost

Tags: android, android-launcher

I want to have a full screen ***without the white part***.

So where the red lines are, i want to have my Tabhost.

Is it possible to have a fullscreen layout? and no white part?

**If so, Here is the picture:**

[image: Picture]

**This is my layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabHost
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#191919" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="nav_header_vertical_spacing">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="nav_header_height">160dp</dimen>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: You can try putting android:padding="0dp" for outermost linear layout and use match_parent instead of fill parent

Comment: Or try putting **negative** padding. I.e.: `-16dp`

Comment: i tried this but than the TabHost is exactly at this invisible frame :(

Comment: By the way, `fill_parent` has been deprecated about 5 years ago. Use `match_parent`, instead.

Comment: a negativ padding doesnt help :(

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to use a custom theme by modifying your current one.

Comment: Do you have other ideas?

Comment: in values folder, do you see a (dimens.xml) file?? if you do, post in your Q to check

Comment: i post the dimens.xml wait

Comment: i added the dimens.xlm

Comment: well change to 0dp on these 2 and retry (<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>)

Comment: my app doesnt start any more :(

Comment: spooky -- whats the error say in the logcat

Comment: you mean me? did it fix it?

Comment: I've just removed and improved your question without `java` tag, that has nothing to do with java.and please let's see the full codes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove these lines:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Which (the values) come from the `dimens.xml` file.

And let's mention it, That is not your `Activity`'s full code, This is just the content which you are refering to another `Layout.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the **0dp of the top level Activity Layout**. I am directly setting to '0dp' here in code to show but use of 'res/values/dimens.xml'(Dimension resource) file is better to set these values. **Works on both RelativeLayout and LinearLayout**.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" >
```

Comment: Why `sp` and not `dp`?

Comment: You should never use SP for layout sizes, paddings or margins. SP is only dedicated for text size.